# Task<string> does not contain a definition for GetAwaiter()

Tags: c#

I Am trying to authenticate URL credentials but I am getting this error as:

> Task does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter'

```
public class Methods
{
    public static async Task<JObject> Get(string url, string username, string password)
    {
        var credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
        HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler { Credentials = credentials };
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
        // client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            return JObject.Parse(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
        }
        return new JObject { response.StatusCode };
    }
}

public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    // Methods RestMethod = new Methods();
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    var data = await Methods.Get("http://www.myportal.com/api/now/table/core_company", "user@myportal.com", "Password123");
    return View();
}
```

[image]

Comment: What version of the Framework are you targetting in your project?  Remember that async/await are available only on .NET 4.5+

Comment: There's a big difference between `Task<>` does not contain a definition for `GetAwaiter` (as per your body) and `string` does not contain a definition for `GetAwaiter` as per your title.

Comment: It does sound like you're just using an old framework though...